# Como modificar um atributo de um objeto em um ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu criei um `ArrayList(objetoQueCriei)`, e gostaria de durante a execução do programa mudar o valor dos atributos desses objetos no array. Tem algum comando para fazer isso?

Tentei usar o comando `set`, mas teria que substituir o objeto desse índice, e não substituir um valor de um atributo do objeto.

Comment: Tente `listaDeObjetos.get(indice).setAtributoQualquer("Valor Novo");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que o @DenerCarvalho disse está corretíssimo, só vou postar aqui pois quero mencionar outra observação:

```
listaDeObjetos.get(indice).setAtributoQualquer("Valor Novo");
```

Como `listaDeObjetos` mantem apenas a referência do objeto, você pode passar a refência para outro objeto e manipular, ficará mais simples, por exemplo:

```
MeuObjeto temp = listaDeObjetos.get(indice);
temp.setAtributoQualquer("Valor Novo");
```

Espero ter ajudado!!